# Erro no adb.exe ao executar "ionic cordova run android --device"

Tags: ionic, app, cmd

Estou tentando rodar meu app no celular e dá esse erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Até ontem estava funcionando e já havia testado no celular várias vezes. Quando atualizei o ionic começou a aparecer essa mensagem do adb.exe.

Estou com tudo atualizado, USB debug ativado no celular, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Tenta executar o comando **adb devices** e verifica se teu celular aparece na lista de devices, se não aparecer você precisa instalar os drivers do dispositivo.

Comment: O dispositivo aparecia e mesmo assim o erro persistia! Mas no outro dia já estava funcionando, acho que era problema com o cabo usb que não conseguia transferir pro celular. Obrigada!